# error curl: (3) <url> malformed shell script

Tags: json, shell, curl

i had a shellscript for export json data but the CURL is getting error malformed..
i'm new for curl anyone can help me please?

this is my cURL

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic cm9iZXJ0aDpDMGI0ZDFiN9000" --globoff $JSON_FILE "https://telkomsel.jasperwireless.com/provision/api/v1/sims?export&page=1&limit=3000&sort=monthToDateVoiceUsage&dir=ASC&search=[{"property":"acctId","type":"LONG_EQUALS","value":100090713,"id":"acctId"}]"
```

please help me

Comment: That last parameter has double quotes inside double quotes - that's not going to work well. Change the outer ones to singles: `"https:...."acctId"}]"` to `'https:...."acctId"}]'`, or escape all the inner ones: `"https:....\"acctId\"}]"`. Also, while you're at it, double-quote that variable - `$JSON_FILE` to `"$JSON_FILE"`.

Comment: @Amadan still not worked.. is that any wrong in -X GET --header??